# excel formulaR1C1 char length

Tags: excel, vba

Visual Basic in Excel is pushing a part of the formula below on a second line. How do i keep it on one line or make it work on multiple lines?

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*DUPLICATE*"",RC[+3])),""Duplicate"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*ABBREV*AM or PM*"",RC[+3])),""Prohibited Abbreviation"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*ABBREV*>*<*"",RC[+3])),""Prohibited Abbreviation"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*ABBREV*Q*"",RC[+3])),""Prohibited Abbreviation"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*ABBREV*U*IU*"",RC[+3])),""Prohibited Abbreviation"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*Out of Stock*"",RC[+3])),""CMOP Out of Stock"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*SIG TOO LONG*"",RC[+3])),""Sig Too Long To Process"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*CMOP STOC*"",RC[+3])),""Quantity"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""MISSPELLIN*"",RC[+3])),""Misspelling"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*MANUF*B*ORDER*"",RC[+3])),""Manufacturer'S Backorder"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*EXPIRED ADDRES*"",RC[+3])),""Expired Address"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*NOT STOCKED*LOW USAGE*"",RC[+3])),""Not Stock-Low usage"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*PRODUCT D*C*"",RC[+3])),""Product Discontinued"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*REFRIG*PO BOX*"",RC[+3])),""Refrig Item/PO Box Address"",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""*CORRECT*RESUBMIT*"",RC[+3])),""Correct Qty & Resubmit"","" "")))))))))))))))"""`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split formula text across lines in the VBA editor using carefully-placed quotes, underscores and ampersands:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(15>10, " & _ '<~ quote, ampersand and underscore
    "12345, " & _
    "67890)"

End Sub
```

[image: newline]

That being said, `ActiveCell` can be tricky, and the formula you're writing out is... complex. Could you perhaps design a `Select...Case` statement in your design to result in a more readable experience for folks who might be maintaining your code?